# Is there an equivalent tool like ruby-prof for node.js?

Tags: node.js, ruby, jestjs

I want to profile a Jest test, but I only want to see the behavior for some specific methods. In ruby, I can do that with ruby-prof, but is there an equivalent tool like it for node.js or jest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.time` in node.js for the same if that's what you're looking for.

```
function myMethodInNode(){
  return 'hello world'
}
console.time("time starts for myMethodInNode");
 
myMethodInNode();
 
console.timeEnd("time ends for myMethodInNode");
```

Comment: sure, thanks but also I want to know the memory consume and the CPU use

Comment: See if this helps: https://raygun.com/blog/improve-node-performance/